# Confusion about sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, sizeof, addition, integer-promotion

I'm confused about `sizeof` operator in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char num1=1, num2=2, result;
    result = num1 + num2;
    printf("Size of result: %d \n",sizeof result);
    printf("Size of result: %d \n",sizeof(num1+num2));
}
```

The results are 1 and 4 respectively. Why does this happen?

Comment: `sizeof(num1+num2)` is logically wrong.

Comment: @i486 What do you mean?

Comment: @jwqwerty: Not logically wrong per se, but useless, as you're obtaining size of a temporary object that exists only for the duration of determining its size. In day-to-day usage, you'd be looking for `sizeof(num1)+sizeof(num2)` if you e.g. want to allocate space to serialize the data.

Comment: @jwqwerty `sizeof` is used to get the size of data type like `sizeof (int), sizeof (my_struct)` or size of specific variable/object `sizeof my_var, sizeof abc`. Maybe you want to write `sizeof num1 + sizeof num2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is of `char` type, therefore `sizeof` is giving `1` while `num1+num2` promoted to `int` type and therefore it gives `4` (size of `int`).

Note that when an arithmetic operation is performed on a type smaller than that of `int` and all of it's value can be represented by `int` then result will be promoted to `int` type.

Comment: Why is num1+num2 promoted to int type?

Comment: @jwqwerty; Because of arithmetic operation.

Comment: @ haccks3 Then I guess in the line "result = num1 + num2", num1+num2 should also be promoted to int because it involves arithemetic operation?

Comment: @jwqwerty; It's the result of `num1 + num2` that is promoted to `int`. Assigning this result to a `char` type will not change the type of that variable.

Comment: @ haccks3 Oh I get it! Thanks!!

Comment: @jwqwerty: The result of the operation may not fit in the same type as the original, so type promotion is applied. Take `unsigned char a=200,b=200` - if you add them, you get 400, which won't fit. If you still insist on writing this to `unsigned char result=a+b;` result will be 144, because the variable gets truncated, data is lost because the container won't fit it. But during the addition, the 'temporary' container is expanded.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR answer:

- `sizeof result` is same as `sizeof(char)`.
- `sizeof(num1+ num2)` is same as `sizeof (int)` <sup>**why?**</sup>

In your case, they produce 1 (guaranteed by standard) and 4 (may vary), respectively.

**That said**, `sizeof` produces a result of type `size_t`, so you should `%zu` format specifier to print the value.

---

**Why:**

First, for the addition operator `+`, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6

> If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   them.

Regarding *usual arithmetic conversions*, §6.3.1.8/p1

> [....] Otherwise, the **integer promotions** are performed on both operands.[...]

and then from §6.3.1.1,/p2,

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.

So, `sizeof(num1+num2)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

num1 + num2 is becoming integer and hence the output is 4 whereas result is char which outputs 1.

You can refer this article [Integer Promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/):

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is
>   converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.
>   These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged
>   by the integer promotions.

Answer (score 0):

the size of one char is 1byte, a char can hold values up to 127(unsigned up to 255).
when you say something like (a + b) a temporary variable is created and used to add a to b, because a and b can hold only 127, they are promoted by the compiler to be an int, just to be sure.

which is logical because if a = 100 and b = 100, the user would like to see 200 when he adds them and not 73 (which is the result of an overflow).